# Relational Database Schema to store multiple variants of a data set

Tags: database, relational-database, database-schema

I would like to create a db schema for a relational DB for a little project.
In that schema I would like to store recipes for example Pasta Carbonara.
The schema would be something like:

(ID,Name,Ingredient1,..,Ingredient10,sourceURL) for the sake of simplicity we assume every recipe only requires a maximum of 10 different Ingredients.

Now I would like to get my recipes from different databases. But since everyone has their own version of a recipe there will be slight differences in a recipe.

In my Carbonara example it would be like

Pasta, Eggs,Bacon,Cream, Chives  from SourceUrl1
Pasta, Eggs,Bacon,Parmesan, Chives from SourceUrl2
............ from SourceUrl3

I would like to store all variations of the same dish in one dataset in my schema. Is there a concept on how to store the data with less reduncancy as possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution:

[image]

...

Some tips:

For the sake of [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), do not put recipe name and ingredients in the same table.

There is a specialized forum for DB questions:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/